# How to leave a trace of locus of parametric curve in desmos

Tags: fourier-series, desmos

In [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o26yst07rb) desmos graph I'm trying to understand epicycles and want to know if there is a way to leave the trace for the locus of the green and red points:

[image]

By default desmos is creating a slider for `t` instead of a continuous range `[0, 2pi]`.
But is there a way to tell desmos to create a range and not a slider?

Comment: You may want to check [Parametric: Cycloid](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eg5he4xpg9) to have an idea.

Comment: @soupless nice, but aren't you fixing `a` in that cycloid? In my graph I want `n` to be a variable, not a slider...

Comment: For example, I need `v(2)` to give the vector `(cos2t, sin2t)`. so I can't let `n` be a slider...

Comment: Just pass $t$ in $v$. Like $v(t)$.

Comment: @soupless ty do you mean `v(n, t)` ?

Comment: Instead of doing $v(2)$, try doing $v(2t)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working XD https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ekjzl3mme0   @soupless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is a way to make ranges, using the special variable $t$. Since you used $t$ as a slider in your graph, I had to modify it in order for the ranges to work. As @soupless said, if you take a look at [Paremetric: Cycloid](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eg5he4xpg9), it shows how you can follow the path of any functionally defined curve. In your case, because you use the function $v$ in more than one line, I would set $t$ as a parameter instead of a global variable. That way, you get a more compact form as shown in [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9j3jxpjhlb) graph:
[image]
However, since you want the *locus*, not the *path traced by each point*, just replace each $t_1$ with $2\pi$:
[image]
Now you can find the locus of any epicycle, not just the one you described.